# Filtering FontDialog to TrueType fonts

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Designing a Custom Font Dialog/Selector for C# that filters out non true type fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644007/designing-a-custom-font-dialog-selector-for-c-sharp-that-filters-out-non-true-ty)

How do I filter the fonts in a `FontDialog` to only TrueType fonts?  I've been messing around with it trying to figure out yet no luck, can anyone help me?

Comment: I believe this is what you looking for:

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644007/designing-a-custom-font-dialog-selector-for-c-sharp-that-filters-out-non-true-ty

Answer (score 1):

I've found an explanation of this problem at http://c-madeeasy.blogspot.com/2011/11/unsolved-this-is-not-true-type-font.html. So I think the only option is to implement your own font chooser dialog.