# How to force font dialog inside property grid to use pixel size unit

Tags: c#, fonts, propertygrid

I need to make sure my image text to be same size when DPI is changed therefore I must use font with "Pixel" unit but font dialog changing unit to "Point". I'm using font dialog inside property grid:

[image]

```
public Font TextFont { get; set; }
```

How can I force font dialog to use "Pixel" unit so watermark text size will be same in every DPI?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [custom font dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644007/designing-a-custom-font-dialog-selector-for-c-sharp-that-filters-out-non-true-ty).
Change the Font that's being displayed by the property grid and the property grid will show the units that the font currently has. The default font dialog creates a new Font that has Point units for any font change.