# Is there a way to set Font Dialog for show only a personalized set of fonts?

Tags: vb.net

Creating a PDF with iTextSharp I need to let the user choose the fonts but with limitations about min and max size and also to a few list of fonts, maybe a list of fonts thay I will add to the resources folder of the program

**Is there a way to set  Font Dialog for show only a personalized set of fonts?, by example the ones on the myapppath/resources folder?**

```
Dim myFont, mySize As String

Using dlg As New frmFonts

    dlg.FontMustExist = True

    dlg.MinSize = 9
    dlg.MaxSize = 14

    dlg.ShowEffects = False

    If dlg.ShowDialog <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
        myFont = dlg.Font.Name
        mySize = dlb.Font.Size
    End If

End Using
```

---

**Attempted solution as suggested by @Tyler**

Below is the code with automatic conversion from C# to VB.NET

I'm getting errors on the lines marked with **

error 1) Value of type 'FontListBox' cannot be converted to 'Control'

error 2) Conversions operators cannot convert from a type to the same type

```
Partial Public Class MyFontDialog
Inherits Form
Private _fontListBox As FontListBox
Private _fontSizeListBox As ListBox

Public Sub New()
    'InitializeComponent();

    _fontListBox = New FontListBox()
    AddHandler _fontListBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf OnfontListBoxSelectedIndexChanged
    _fontListBox.Size = New Size(200, Height)
    **Controls.Add(_fontListBox)**

    _fontSizeListBox = New ListBox()
    **_fontSizeListBox.Location = New Point(_fontListBox.Width, 0)**

    Controls.Add(_fontSizeListBox)
End Sub

Private Sub OnfontListBoxSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    _fontSizeListBox.Items.Clear()
    **Dim font As Font = TryCast(_fontListBox.SelectedItem, Font)**
    If font IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each style As FontStyle In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(FontStyle))
            If font.FontFamily.IsStyleAvailable(style) Then
                _fontSizeListBox.Items.Add(style)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
End Class

Friend Class FontListBox
    Friend Size As Size
    Public Event SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    **Public Shared Widening Operator CType(v As FontListBox) As FontListBox**
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Operator
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have a custom control, so yes it is possible. Take a look here, for sure will help you [Designing a Custom Font Dialog/Selector for C# that filters out non true type fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644007/designing-a-custom-font-dialog-selector-for-c-sharp-that-filters-out-non-true-ty)

**Edit:**

In case the link will be broken, here is the part of code that you are interested for. Just change this IF `If font.FontFamily.IsStyleAvailable(style) Then` with your filtered FontName and you have done.

```
Private Sub OnfontListBoxSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
_fontSizeListBox.Items.Clear()
Dim font As Font = TryCast(_fontListBox.SelectedItem, Font)
If font IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each style As FontStyle In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(FontStyle))
        If font.FontFamily.IsStyleAvailable(style) Then
            _fontSizeListBox.Items.Add(style)
        End If
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT2:**
Considerate your latest comment.. try to slit the 2 class in 2 vb files. Exactly like that:

```
Partial Public Class MyFontDialog
Inherits Form
Private _fontListBox As FontListBox
Private _fontSizeListBox As ListBox

Public Sub New()
    'InitializeComponent();

    _fontListBox = New FontListBox()
    AddHandler _fontListBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf OnfontListBoxSelectedIndexChanged
    _fontListBox.Size = New Size(200, Height)
    Controls.Add(_fontListBox)

    _fontSizeListBox = New ListBox()
    _fontSizeListBox.Location = New Point(_fontListBox.Width, 0)

    Controls.Add(_fontSizeListBox)
End Sub

Private Sub OnfontListBoxSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    _fontSizeListBox.Items.Clear()
    Dim font As Font = TryCast(_fontListBox.SelectedItem, Font)
    If Font IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each style As FontStyle In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(FontStyle))
            If Font.FontFamily.IsStyleAvailable(style) Then
                _fontSizeListBox.Items.Add(style)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Second class:

```
Public Class FontListBox
Inherits ListBox
Private _fonts As New List(Of Font)()
Private _foreBrush As Brush

Public Sub New()
    DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
    ItemHeight = 20
    For Each ff As FontFamily In FontFamily.Families
        ' determine the first available style, as all fonts don't support all styles
        Dim availableStyle As System.Nullable(Of FontStyle) = Nothing
        For Each style As FontStyle In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(FontStyle))
            If ff.IsStyleAvailable(style) Then
                availableStyle = style
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If availableStyle.HasValue Then
            Dim font As Font = Nothing
            Try
                ' do your own Font initialization here
                ' discard the one you don't like :-)
                font = New Font(ff, 12, availableStyle.Value)
            Catch
            End Try
            If font IsNot Nothing Then
                _fonts.Add(font)
                Items.Add(font)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    If _fonts IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each font As Font In _fonts
            font.Dispose()
        Next
        _fonts = Nothing
    End If
    If _foreBrush IsNot Nothing Then
        _foreBrush.Dispose()
        _foreBrush = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Public Overrides Property ForeColor() As Color
    Get
        Return MyBase.ForeColor
    End Get
    Set
        MyBase.ForeColor = Value
        If _foreBrush IsNot Nothing Then
            _foreBrush.Dispose()
        End If
        _foreBrush = Nothing
    End Set
End Property

Private ReadOnly Property ForeBrush() As Brush
    Get
        If _foreBrush Is Nothing Then
            _foreBrush = New SolidBrush(ForeColor)
        End If
        Return _foreBrush
    End Get
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(e As DrawItemEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnDrawItem(e)
    If e.Index < 0 Then
        Return
    End If

    e.DrawBackground()
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
    Dim bounds As Rectangle = e.Bounds
    Dim font As Font = DirectCast(Items(e.Index), Font)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(font.Name, font, ForeBrush, bounds.Left, bounds.Top)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Linking to an existing question can be done in a comment.

Comment: @Tyler thanks for the support. If I understand well I need to create a new MyFont class translating the example code on C# to VB.NET. I'm having problem with the line 'Controls.Add(_fontListBox)' as Visual Studio say Value of type "FontListBox" cannot be converted to "Control"

Comment: @fedeteka you must use also the code of the first post and not only the one of the answer.. or maybe the conversion from C# to VB.NET has fail.

Comment: Yes, I'm using all the code. I edited the question to post all the code after the conversion. Maybe the trouble is the suggested solution of Visual Studio 'Private _fontListBox As FontListBox'

Comment: No more errors now on the code. Thanks! I'm going to try to apply the suggested solution. If I'm have success I will post the whole code. If not I will post my doubt.

Comment: Nice, let me know.

Comment: @Tyler I really have trouble with the implementation, I don´t know what is the right way, mark this as a correct answer and open another question or post the question here?

Comment: If is another problem, yes. But if respect the title of the post.. you can just edit your first post. :)