# How to make a Font Combobox in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts, combobox

I want to make a combobox in a c# .NET 4.5 Windows Forms application  (note: not WPF) that displays all the truetype installed font on the system and that every font is formatted with the font it's representing ("Times" formatted with Times, "Arial" formatted with arial and so on).

How to do this?

Comment: On the client system?

Comment: Yes, on the client system

Comment: I don't think that you can display client's fonts for the same reasons that block you from managing user's files

Comment: @AleTheFe - you can use WPF combobox in Winforms window as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ComboBox.DrawItem` eventhandler.

```
public YourForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ComboBoxFonts.DrawItem += ComboBoxFonts_DrawItem;           
    ComboBoxFonts.DataSource = System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families.ToList();
}

private void ComboBoxFonts_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    var fontFamily = (FontFamily)comboBox.Items[e.Index];
    var font = new Font(fontFamily, comboBox.Font.SizeInPoints);

    e.DrawBackground();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(font.Name, font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
}
```

For using `ComboBox.DrawItem` you need set `ComboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families`, something like this

```
List<string> fonts = new List<string>();

foreach (FontFamily font in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families)
{
    fonts.Add(font.Name);
}

.................. your logic
```

Comment: Yes, but doing this I'll have only the names of the fonts. The'll not be formatted

Comment: @AleTheFe You can use the name to find the font though... only problem is that the regular combobox doesn't take a font for each item (as far as I know)

Comment: @EpicKip this is exactly what I thought about so far :'(

Comment: @AleTheFe Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644007/designing-a-custom-font-dialog-selector-for-c-sharp-that-filters-out-non-true-ty is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following a project published couple of years ago here, https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318174/Creating-a-WYSIWYG-font-ComboBox-using-Csharp

But instead of doing that, you can follow the Narek Noreyan steps and adding more, use a rich text box, whose text font will be changed after selecting a font family from the combo box.

Some code snippet here,

```
using System.Drawing.Text;
void mainformload(object sender, EventArgs s)
{
    InstalledFontCollection inf=new      InstalledFontCollection();
    foreach(Font family font in inf.Families)
        combobox.Items.Add(font.Name); //filling the font name
    //get the font name of the rich text box text
    combobox.Text=this.richtextbox.Font.Name.ToString();
    }
void comboboxselectionchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richtextbox.Font=new Font(combobox.text, richtextbox.Font.Size);
}
```