# How to set the SelectedValue of a ComboBox used as Font selector?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, combobox

I have a combobox which I fill font's inside. The method I use to do so is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037189/how-to-make-a-font-combobox-in-c) link. I will share the answer from that question here.

```
public YourForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ComboBoxFonts.DrawItem += ComboBoxFonts_DrawItem;           
    ComboBoxFonts.DataSource = System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families.ToList();
}

private void ComboBoxFonts_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    var fontFamily = (FontFamily)comboBox.Items[e.Index];
    var font = new Font(fontFamily, comboBox.Font.SizeInPoints);

    e.DrawBackground();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(font.Name, font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
}
```

now I have only made 1 change to this code and that's this :

```
cmbFonts.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
```

there is no problem with loading fonts and it's working but I try to set the selectedvalue on my form load. For example I try to set font named "arial". In order to do so I use this :

```
var dataSource = cmbFonts.DataSource as List<FontFamily>;
int res = -1;
try
{
  res = dataSource.IndexOf(new FontFamily(StaticVariables.FontName));
}
catch { }
if (res != -1)
  cmbFonts.SelectedIndex = res;
```

now when I do this I get `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` error because I did not add any Items to `Combobox` I bind a `DataSource` therefore when I try to set `SelectedIndex` I get this error and I know that, I also tried this :

```
cmbFonts.SelectedValue = StaticVariables.FontName;
```

but when I run my code with breakpoints in Visual studio I see that my `SelectedValue` never changes. Before the line is executed I see null and after the execution I still see null in `SelectedValue`, I checked my StaticVariables.FontName variable and the font is presented in there.

I've also tried to use `combobox.Text` property but no luck, it's like `SelectedValue`, was empty string before and still same after I skip it with breakpoint.

TL;DR:
I try to select an item on form load in combobox which I filled with `DataSource`

Comment: Take the extra-simplified Font Selector Combo (`cboFontFamily`) from here: [Properly draw text using Graphics Path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53074638/7444103) (at the bottom of everything). Then if you want to select a specific Item, just set `cboFontFamily.SelectedItem = [A Family Name];`. Using a collection of FontFamilies directly is costly and *dangerous*. You can work with just the name (a simple string) and create a Font from only when needed. Note: that method allows you can print Fonts not usually available. BTW, `OwnerDrawVariable` is required: Fonts have all different heights.

Comment: Anyway, I'd suggest to build a custom ComboBox control to better handle some *internals*. You'll notice sooner or later.

Comment: If you **install** the Font (the Font files go to the System Fonts repository), then of course it will be found. It uses the same `FontFamily.Families` collection you're using now (in a *safer* way). Unless you use the `PrivateFontCollection.AddFontFile` (or `AddMemoryFont`) feature: those Fonts are local to your app. You can handle them anyway, using a *companion* collection of Font families names. That's one of the reasons I suggested a custom ComboBox :)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Everything worked perfectly :) About your previous question; yes. I do install the font and they go to System Fonts repo so the combobox is showing and also applying my custom fonts ^^ Now there is just 1 question remaining, how do I accept your comment as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a custom owner-drawn ComboBox class (here, named **`FontListCombo`**) that shows *compatible* System Font Families, representing each ComboBox Item using the [FontFamily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.fontfamily) name as the Item Text and the corresponding Font to draw the Item's text (a classic ComboBox Font selector, in practice).

The Custom Control automatically fills itself, at run-time, with the list of available Fonts in the System. It also react to [`WM_FONTCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-fontchange) messages (broadcast when the System Font pool changes; e.g., a Font is added to or removed from the `Fonts` folder), to updated the Font list and reflect the change (to also avoid to try and use a Font that doesn't exist anymore).

The text of the ComboBox Items is drawn using [TextRenderer.DrawText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext) instead of [Graphics.DrawString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring), since the former grants sharper results in this context.

The `ComboBox.Items` collection is represented by a collection of **`FontObject`** class objects, a public class that stores some of the properties of each FontFamily and also exposes a couple of static methods used internally to return a Font object or a FontFamily object, calling the corresponding public methods of the custom ComboBox:

- The **`GetSelectedFont(SizeInPoints, FontStyle)`** method return a Font object from the current `ComboBox.SelectedItem`.
- **`GetSelectedFontFamily()`** return the FontFamily object from the current `ComboBox.SelectedItem`.

It also overrides `ToString()`, to return a summary of values of its properties.

This kind of object container is a better fit here: storing FontFamily object as the ConboBox Items would, most surely, create different sorts of problems, the most visible and tragic is that some FontFamily objects become invalid over time or even right after they have been stored. These objects are not meant to be stored permanently to begin with, so it's not exactly a surprise.

As shown in the example, to get the current Font and FontFamily from the `ComboBox.SelecteItem`:
(here, the ComboBox instance is named **`cboFontList`**)

```
private void cboFontList_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Font font = cboFontList.GetSelectedFont(this.Font.SizeInPoints, FontStyle.Regular);
    FontFamily family = cboFontList.GetSelectedFontFamily();
    string fontDetails = (cboFontList.SelectedItem as FontListCombo.FontObject).ToString();
}
```

The FontObject class stores some important details of the FontFamily, such as the [Cell Ascent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.fontfamily.getcellascent), the [Cell Descent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.fontfamily.getcelldescent), the [EM Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.fontfamily.getemheight) and the [Line Spacing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.fontfamily.getlinespacing).
Some details on how to use these features are described here:

[Properly draw text using Graphics Path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53074638/7444103)
[Fonts and text metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/fonts-and-font-metrics)

**This is how it works:**

[image: Custom ComboBox Font Selector]

---

**FontListCombo Custom Control:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class FontListCombo : ComboBox
{
    private List<FontObject> fontList = null;

    public FontListCombo() {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if (!DesignMode) GetFontFamilies();
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Items.Count == 0) || e.Index < 0) return;
        e.DrawBackground();
        var flags = TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
        using (var family = new FontFamily(this.GetItemText(Items[e.Index])))
        using (var font = new Font(family, 10F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point)) {
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, family.Name, font, e.Bounds, this.ForeColor, flags);
        }
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        base.OnDrawItem(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMeasureItem(MeasureItemEventArgs e) {
        base.OnMeasureItem(e);
        e.ItemHeight = this.Font.Height + 4;
    }

    private void GetFontFamilies()
    {
        this.fontList = new List<FontObject>();

        fontList.AddRange(FontFamily.Families
            .Where(f => f.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular))
            .Select(f => new FontObject(f)).ToArray());
        this.DisplayMember = "FamilyName";
        this.ValueMember = "EmHeight";
        this.DataSource = fontList;
    }

    public FontFamily GetSelectedFontFamily()
    {
        if (this.SelectedIndex < 0) return null;
        return FontObject.GetSelectedFontFamily((FontObject)this.SelectedItem);
    }

    public Font GetSelectedFont(float sizeInPoints, FontStyle style)
    {
        if (this.SelectedIndex < 0) return null;
        return FontObject.GetSelectedFont((FontObject)this.SelectedItem, sizeInPoints, style);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case WM_FONTCHANGE:  // The System Font pool has changed
                GetFontFamilies();
                break;
        }
    }

    public class FontObject
    {
        public FontObject(FontFamily family) { GetFontFamilyInfo(family); }
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        public int EmHeight { get; set; }
        public int CellAscent { get; set; }
        public int CellDescent { get; set; }
        public int LineSpacing { get; set; }

        private void GetFontFamilyInfo(FontFamily family)
        {
            this.FamilyName = family.Name;
            this.EmHeight = family.GetEmHeight(FontStyle.Regular);
            this.CellAscent = family.GetCellAscent(FontStyle.Regular);
            this.CellDescent = family.GetCellDescent(FontStyle.Regular);
            this.LineSpacing = family.GetLineSpacing(FontStyle.Regular);
        }
        internal static FontFamily GetSelectedFontFamily(FontObject fobj) 
            => new FontFamily(fobj.FamilyName);

        internal static Font GetSelectedFont(FontObject fobj, float sizeInPoints, FontStyle style) 
            => new Font(GetSelectedFontFamily(fobj), sizeInPoints, style);

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(this.FamilyName);
            sb.AppendLine($"Em Height: {this.EmHeight}");
            sb.AppendLine($"Cell Ascent: {this.CellAscent}");
            sb.AppendLine($"Cell Descent: {this.CellDescent}");
            sb.AppendLine($"Line Spacing: {this.LineSpacing}");
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```